# What do you call a student who studies extra at home to become proficient?

Tags: meaning, nouns, british-english

What is the British English term for someone (a student) who goes home after classes and practices the lesson learned that day, or becomes proficient in the lesson taught?  It is not a positive reference but a negative name-calling term.

Comment: A [swot](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/swot), maybe?

Answer (score 3):

In the negative sense, a swot.

> **swot**
> *British informal*; *derogatory*
> A person who studies very hard.
>
> - *The unloved school [swots](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swot) of the 20th century have blossomed into the alpha group of the 21st*.
>   <sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

*Swotting up* is really just like revising for exams but being a bit of a *swot* has the connotation of being always in a book, always working, never giving thought to 'lesser' activities.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***grind***

> A person who works or studies too much.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grind)